# Flexible website structure

Tags: html, node.js, structure

I used to develop websites the following way:

```
footer.php
header.php
navigation.php
index.php
contact.php
```

Doing it this way allowed me to only make changes in one place.
For example if I wanted to change footer information. All I would change is footer.php

I don't want to use php to do this anymore. What are someone of the alternative solutions to creating a flexible website structure. Would `node.js` achieve this?

Comment: I'm interested in learning about alternative ways to structure websites

Comment: Node.js itself - wouldn't, but there are plenty of template engines [out there](http://toolbox.no.de/categories/Templating) ([jade](http://jade-lang.com/), for example)

Comment: Yes it is possible to achieve similar effects with Node.js. But instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at existing MVC frameworks for both PHP (Symfony, Zend, CodeIgniter, ...) or Node.js (Express.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, node.js has awesome web frameworks and templating languages. The biggest difference will be that instead of maintaining a set of documents (header, footer, index, contact) served *from* a web server, you'll be writing a server itself that can route URLs to functions. It's a bit of a paradigm shift, but it it gives you a lot of power, and flexibility.

My favorite node.js web framework is [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/guide.html). Welcome to the node community!

Comment: if were talking about JS as a framework, im all about backbone.js.

Comment: love backbone.js for client-side stuff too; Rails or Node for the backend work really well with backbone on the front.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: To clarify, I understood you to mean, "I don't want to use PHP in this manner," as opposed to, "I don't want to use PHP at all." If you actually did mean the latter, then please ignore this answer... :)]

node.js is not a web server, and is completely the wrong tool for what you're looking to do. It seems you've done enough development of this sort of site to have learned the limitations involved. That's good, so I think the next logical step for you would be to learn an MVC framework like [`Fuel`](http://fuelphp.com/), [`Symfony`](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [`CodeIgniter`](http://codeigniter.com/), or [`Zend`](http://framework.zend.com/).

Comment: Or Express.js, if he really is intent on developing with Node.js.

Comment: PHP isn't web server either. Or perharps topic starter was meaning something about `include` directive. In that case take a look at `require` and node's [modules system](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: yea, not sure you meant "web server" but node.js is a fine way to develop websites...it would be completely clientside, so very different than what he would be used to as a php designer "paradigm shift" is right! @Christopher Scott

Comment: @RGB Node.js is not client-side at all. Maybe you are confusing with client-side javascript MVC libraries like Backbone.js.

Comment: Yeah sorry, poor wording on my part. I understood the OP to be asking for a better way to structure a PHP-based site. I meant to imply that node.js (in and of itself) is not an equivalent to your typical Apache/PHP setup.

Comment: @AlexHowansky How isn't it an equivalent for a LAMP stack?

Comment: Heh, let me rephrase. I understood the question to be, "What's a better way to structure a PHP-based application?" If that's accurate, then node.js is not going to be anywhere in the answer. So, I didn't mean to imply that it's not as capable, just unrelated, given my interpretation.

Comment: lol poor wording on my part too...was thinking about backbone as a side note though.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails for the win! personally i find php to be poisionous these days, but i did it for many years...it depends though on your ability to adapt to a new language and your level as a programmer.

if youre really into your php skills, you can stick with Zend..

Really what you want to focus on is an MVC (Model View Controller) architecture for your designs, it breaks everything down perfectly, leaving everything to be defined once, and in its place.